# DropTarget for Ext Window

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I need to implement drop target for Ext Window. The windows can be dropped anywhere but when they are dropped inside DropZone then i need to call a function that will change it's layout. The problem is that the drop events are not called.

Here is how i define drop target (it is a floating panel, below code called in initComponent):

```
    this.on('render', function(w) {
                w.dropTarget = Ext.create('Ext.dd.DropTarget', w.getEl());
                w.dropTarget.nofifyDrop = function(source, evt, data) {
                    console.log('notifyDrop');
                };

                w.dropTarget.notifyEnter = function() {
                    console.log('notifyEnter');
                };
            },this);
```

Here is how i define drop source. When window has draggable config then it has dd property that i am trying to configure

```
    listeners:{
                    scope:this,
                    close:function(w) {
                        this.removeWindow(w);
                    },
                    show:function(w) {
                        console.log('win', w.dd);
                        w.dd.afterValidDrop = function() {
                            console.log('after valid drop');
                        } 
                        w.dd.onDragDrop = function() {
                            console.log('on drag drop');
                        }
                        w.dd.onStartDrag = function() {
                            console.log('starting drag');
                        }
                    },
```

The problem is that not a single function is called, no action logged into console. When i switch from window to panel with floating and draggable config then the events from DropTarget are called (notifyDrop and notifyEnter) but events from panel are not. How to properly configure Drag&Drop for Window with draggable config or maybe there is a better way to implement what i need.

I also tried to disable draggable for window or panel and specify DropTarget and DragSource myself:

Droptarget now have ddGroup:

```
    this.on('render', function(w) {
        w.dropTarget = Ext.create('Ext.dd.DropTarget', w.getEl(),{
            ddGroup:'winDDGroup',
            notifyDrop:function(source, evt, data) {

            },
            notifyEnter:function() {
                console.log('notifyEnter');
            }
        });
    },this);
```

And drag source (ext window):

```
    var overrides = {
                    startDrag: function(e) {
                        console.log('starting drag');
                        //shortcut to access our element later
                        if (!this.el) {
                            this.el = Ext.get(this.getEl());
                        }
                        //add a css class to add some transparency to our div
                        this.el.addCls('selected');
                        //when we drop our item on an invalid place  we need to return it to its initial position
                        this.initialPosition = this.el.getXY();
                    },
                    onDrag: function(e) {
                        //this.el.moveTo(e.getPageX() - 32, e.getPageY() - 32);
                    },
                    onDragEnter: function(e, id) {
                        console.log('onDragEnter', id);
                        Ext.fly(id).addCls('valid-zone');
                    },
                    onDragOver: function(e, id) {
                        console.log('onDragOver', id);
                        Ext.fly(id).addCls('valid-zone');
                    },
                    onDragOut: function(e, id) {
                        console.log('onDragOut');
                    },
                    onDragDrop: function(e, id) {
                        console.log('on drag Drop');
                        // change the item position to absolute
                        this.el.dom.style.position = 'absolute';
                        //move the item to the mouse position
                        this.el.moveTo(e.getPageX() - 32, e.getPageY() - 32);
                        Ext.fly(id).removeCls('valid-zone');

                    },
                    onInvalidDrop: function() {
                        console.log('invalid drop');
                        this.el.removeCls('valid-zone');
                        //this.el.moveTo(this.initialPosition[0], this.initialPosition[1]);
                    },
                    endDrag: function(e, id) {
                        console.log('end drag');
                        this.el.removeCls('selected');
                        //Ext.fly(id).removeCls('drop-target');
                        //this.el.highlight();
                    }
                };

    ....

                listeners:{
                    scope:this,
                    close:function(w) {
                        this.removeWindow(w);
                    },
                    render:function(w) {
                        var dd = Ext.create('Ext.dd.DragSource', w.getEl(), {
                            ddGroup:'winDDGroup',
                            //isTarget: false
                        });

                        Ext.apply(dd, overrides);
                    },
    }
```

Now when i start dragging the window events are fired but dragging the window over drop zone have no effect. DropTarget events are not fired.

Edit: Again when i switch from window to panel then events from both source and target are fired. Still i need the drag sources to be windows.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue when trying to manipulate the proxy and the drag handle that may help. 
Maybe you should look into [DragTracker](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.dd.DragTracker) or [DragDrop](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.dd.DragDrop) components. Dragtracker will provide you with events for dragstart and drag end among others that you can use to implement your drop logic.

This was roughly my implementation (for panels, but maybe it'll help, i cant really look into it in great depth)

```
//add the listener to afterrender, possibly other
window.on('afterrender', me._setupDragDrop, window);

//do your magic
_setupDragDrop : function(win){
        win.dd = new Ext.dd.DragDrop(win.id);
        win.dd.setHandleElId(win);
            win.dragTracker = new Ext.dd.DragTracker({
                onBeforeStart: function(e) {
                    //do stuff
                },
                onStart: function(e) {
                    //do stuff
                },
                onDrag: function(e) {
                    //do stuff
                },
                onEnd: function(e) {
                    //do stuff
                }
            });
            win.dragTracker.initEl(win.el);
     },
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't work with windows. Overriding default win.dd disables any dragging for window component. I will dig into it. For now i ended up using  dragstart and dragend events wchich are not documented under Ext.window but Ext.util.ComponentDragger which is used by window. Window itself is firing/bubbling these events.